# Не работает ввод сообщения на русском языке, хотя транслитом вводит

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Создал форму отправки сообщения в базу данных через mysql, при заполнении текста на англ языке всё хорошо, но при вводе русских слов в итоге в базе данных в этих ячейках пусто.

Код в html

```html
<html>
<head>

 <title>Запись в БД через форму на php</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="POST" action="http://test1.ru/sega/index.php">
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Имя"/>
  <input name="text" type="text" placeholder="Текст"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Также само заполнение в базу данных

```html
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text'])){

    // Переменные с формы
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    // Параметры для подключения
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = ""; // Пароль БД
    $db_base = "sega"; // Имя БД
    $db_table = "mytable"; // Имя Таблицы БД

    // Подключение к базе данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);
    $mysqli->query ("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");

    // Если есть ошибка соединения, выводим её и убиваем подключение
 if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
     die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
 }
  $mysqli->query (
  "CREATE TABLE `sega`.`mytable`(
      `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `name` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
      `text` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
   `regdate` DATE
  )
  ");

    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (name,text) VALUES ('$name','$text')");

    if ($result == true){
     echo "Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено";
    }else{
     echo "Ваше сообщение не отправлено";
    }
}
?>
```

Помогите в результате несколько раз пробовал добавлять изменяя кодировку CHARACTER SET utf8_general_ci NOT NULL, но безуспешно
[image: Первая строка при вводе слов на русском, вторая строка при вводе слов на английском]

Первая строка при вводе слов на русском, вторая строка при вводе слов на английском

Comment: Проверьте содержимое mysqli->error если там что-то есть, а так же [кодировки](https://php.ru/forum/threads/zapis-russkix-simvolov-v-bazu-mysql.52093/) на соответствие (входную с браузера и её тип в БД)

Comment: Очень странное поведение. Единственное что я мог предположить - таблица была изначально создана с неверным чарсетом, а запрос на создание  в скрипте по очевидным причинам не выполняется

Comment: вроде с чарсетом всё в порядке, потому что если я html прописывал в одном файле с php то он начинает работать как надо и русские слова добавляются, но если html отдельно с привязкой формы к php то всё обратно как писал выше

Comment: насчёт ошибок, не выдаёт, а насчет кодировок я все кодировки проверял, и с тире и без, и другие ставил, и писал как в БД, всё одинаково

Comment: Кодировка html страницы, скрипта php и базы данных должны совпадать